# Website forwarding, keeping original URL

Tags: url, domain-forwarding

We have `example.org` (our main site) registered and hosted on an american server.
We bought `example.gr` domain name in Greece, a local registrar.
We made `.gr` point at `.org` DNS all right.
A visitor types URL `.gr` and sees `.org` in his browser all right, but URL immediately changed to `.org`.
Is there a way to keep URL `.gr` and still see `.org`?
If a `.org` visitor then clicks on a link to `example.org/abcd.php`, could a `.gr` visitor clicking on the same link see the address bar show `example.gr/abcd.php`?

Our American registrar told us to contact Greek registrar and ask for mapping. The Greek registrar basically set an iframe displaying `example.org` and called it `example.gr`. But that was wrong because obviously, each time a visitor would click on something, the address bar would always display one thing only, the same URL all the time, `example.gr`.
So we cancelled that cheap mapping trick down, and I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

You could make an `<iframe>`,

```
<style type=text/css>
    body{margin: 0;overflow:hidden;}
</style>
<iframe src="http://example.org/" style="border: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%" frameBorder="0">
    Browser not compatible.
</iframe>
```

So you'd call this `index.html` and put it on the `example.gr` server.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't class a `iframe` solution the best solution, while this doesn't answer your question directly it does give you an additional and more robust never-mind a more browser friendly site.

The method that I believe is best suited for you is to use `rel="canonical"` on the `.gr` domain referring to `.org` as the master (no redirects). If they visit `.gr` they remain on `.gr` and vice versa on the `.org`. The `.org` will be the master for rankings purposes in Google as same as the `iframe` method.

So to make this possible you do the following:

1. Clone the file contents of the site to another hosting folder so effective you have 2 hosting accounts but these are mirrored.
2. Setup the `.gr` site to use the database of the `.org` site so both sites are exactly the same. (You may need to adjust the base_url) or use a multiple site plugin (if you don't have a SQL then even easier).
3. You will want to use `rel="canonical"` on both the master `.org` and `.gr` as the slave.
4. Optional step (you could even robots the `.gr` site from indexing)

Examples of `rel="canonical"` in action:

In the head of your master site (`.org` domain) you would use the following:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.org/page1"/>
```

In the head of your slave site (`.gr` domain) you would use the following:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.org/page1"/>
```

This basically tells Google that the master is the org, you could even go one step further and *robots.txt* the `.gr` site completely but with this method you will not get a duplicate content slap on the `.gr` with or without robots.

**Using two domains one site WordPress**

Step 1: Go to your General Settings and completely remove the "Blog address (URL)" and save.

Step 2: Add something like the below code to `header.php`:

```
$ThisDomain = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

if($ThisDomain=='example.org' || $ThisDomain=='www.example.org')
{ echo '.org stuff'; }
elseif($ThisDomain=='example.gr' || $ThisDomain=='www.example.gr')
{ echo '.gr stuff'; }
```

Step 3: Ensure `HTTP_HOST` is not set in the SQL.

Comment: How about if there are session cookies?

Comment: You should be able to store cookies based on the base_url rather than statically on the main site. So visiting .gr will give a .gr based cookie and visiting the .org will give a cookie for that domain. They shouldn't need to bounce to from one another, certainly the way the OP has posted this is not his/her intention.

Comment: One of the reasons I mentioned a multiple site plugin as take WordPress or Joomla for example they statically set the main site, you can get plugins to overcome this so it doesn't redirect and cookies are set correctly.

Comment: The most ideal situation would just to redirect .gr to .org but ya ;)

Comment: I meant, how would WordPress be able to use both cookie domaines? Doesn't it only work with one domain? (I know MyBB has this limitation). http://ikailo.com/218/cross-domain-cookie-sharing-wordpress/ seems like too much work. Or this: http://maisonbisson.com/post/14028/wordpress-hacks-managing-multiple-sub-domains/

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you right but yes cookies not compatible without a lot of work... However if you visit the .gr domain, a cookie will be issued, this same cookie won't work if they then went to the .org domain! (but they will be issued a .org cookie) but as stated they shouldn't be redirecting so the cross domain compatibility isn't important as long as they are issued a gr one when visiting the gr site and .org when visiting the main site.

Comment: Correct, but I'm saying, WordPress (I think, because so does MyBB) issues a cookie from the domain it is installed on. Which, to fix, would require a lot of work. I do not believe they actually will be issued a cookie to the domain of ACCESS rather than the domain the site was configured for. In which case, one of the two would fail without modifications.

Comment: Fairly simple in WordPress since cookies are set using SERVER_NAME and HTTP_HOST which can determined using php 'if' in the header of your theme, dunno about MyBB I don't use it - updated answer with WordPress example.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though you're looking for a [parked domain](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/CpanelDocs/ParkedDomains). This is easy to set up if your web host is running cPanel.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using a shared hosting account and have access to the Apache configuration just create another virtual host with a different `ServerName` pointing to the same document root.

Other webservers will have a similar set up, for example just make another `server {}` block for nginx.